# Is there any possibilities to generate same hash key using md5?

Tags: md5, unique-key, api-key

am generating unique api keies using this function and storing into database.

```
strtoupper( md5( uniqid(rand(), TRUE ) ) );
```

is thr any possiblities of generating same hash key by above function???

Comment: use this: echo strtoupper( md5( date('dmYHisu') ) ); - it will make extremely unique key & no collision will be occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the unique value generated by uniqueid function is really pretty unique, there is considerable probability of collision when using MD5 hash algorithm (i.e. different values will result in the same hash value). In fact, MD5 is considered "cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use" by [US-CERT](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068) and if you're concerned about collisions, you should consider using SHA256/SHA512 algorithms instead.

Comment: if i use this: echo strtoupper( md5( date('dmYHisu') ) ); - it will make extremely unique - no collision will be occurs

Comment: You can also use com_create_guid() method to create GUID value in php. Theoretically speaking, the point remains however: with large enough dataset, there will be significant probability of collisions id MD5 is used. In practice, you probably shouldn't worry too much about that since the number of generated API keys is unlikely to exceed a few billions :-).

Answer (score 2):

uniqid is based on the time in milliseconds, combine that with a random prefix and it is extremely unlikely.

See below for more info on uniqid:
[PHP: uniqid - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)